# RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'main' was never awaited error

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio, telethon

I run this test code:

```
import telethon.sync
from telethon import TelegramClient 
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import AddChatUserRequest 
from telethon.tl.functions.contacts import ImportContactsRequest 

api_id = XXXXXXX
api_hash = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXC'

with TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash) as client:
async def main():

client(AddChatUserRequest(-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX, ['username'], fwd_limit=10))
main()
```

And it gives me this:

```
/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/temp_iiec_codefile.py:19: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'main' was never awaited
main()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

What should I do to make the program work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'main' was never awaited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57399157/runtimewarning-coroutine-main-was-never-awaited)

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at `telethon` documentation, [see how it starts event loop](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/basic/quick-start.html):

```
from telethon import TelegramClient


api_id = 12345
api_hash = '0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef'
client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)


async def main():
    me = await client.get_me()
    # etc.


with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```