# Asyncio how to fix sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'xxx' was never awaited

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Building a scraper to scrape multiple pages with async. I created a class but once I want to run the test method I receive 2 errors:

```
TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not callable
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Scraper.page' was never awaited
```

Here is my code:

```
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession

class Scraper(AsyncHTMLSession):
    def __init__(self):
        AsyncHTMLSession.__init__(self)
    
    async def page(self):
        t = await self.get("https://www.somePage.pl/strona/1/")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = Scraper()
    d1 = t.run(t.page())
    print(d1.result)
```

Comment: Await something

Comment: The `page` instance method returns `None` by default. Do you want to `return t`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'main' was never awaited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57399157/runtimewarning-coroutine-main-was-never-awaited)

Comment: I wanna get t  - get requests response. It's being awaited but still receiving this error